# Android ActionbarSherlock Customization

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on a application that has a different appearance depending on the result of an API call. This call returns a set of data, also containing information about the appearance of the app. Since I get this information on the run, I cant edit styles.xml to design the ActionBarSherlock I'm using.

What is was wondering, is there a way to customize the ActionBar solely from code? I mean more than the icon, title or background. But textcolors and menuitems and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like the following where actionbar is a layout with a bunch of buttons that you can restyle programatically

```
//ActionBar Functions
protected void initActionBar()
{
    // Inflate the custom view for action bar
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);

    // Attach to the action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    setActionBar();
}
```

Comment: I have considered doing this, but I feel like I would lose a lot of functionality if I did it this way. I rather keep the actionbar the way it is.

Comment: Fair enough - it's up to you but I have achieved the results you wanted with this method.